# Using a for loop to create cube integers

Tags: python, for-loop

I included problem #1 for context but I need help with problem #2:

Problem #1:
**Write a for loop to cube integers from 11 to 15, inclusive (i.e. including 11 and 15).
You can include a print statement in your for loop to check your work.**

Hint: The output should be: 1331, 1728, 2197, 2774, 3375

```
numbers_to_cube = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

for number in numbers_to_cube:

  print(number**3)
```

Problem #2:
**Now, let's combine the above for loop with creating a list of numbers. Use a list inside the for loop to hold the results; name your list cubed.**

```
cubed = []

for number in numbers_to_cube:

  cubed.append(number**3)

  print(cubed)
```

The result turns out like this:

```
[1331]
[1331, 1728]
[1331, 1728, 2197]
[1331, 1728, 2197, 2744]
[1331, 1728, 2197, 2744, 3375]
```

How do I get just the very last set of numbers?

Comment: Just unindent the `print` line so that it is aligned with the `for`.

Comment: Wow so simple! Thank you! Still learning :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the very last set, move the `print(cubed)` part outside of the for-loop.

```
cubed = []

for number in numbers_to_cube:

  cubed.append(number**3)

print(cubed) # Prints [1331, 1728, 2197, 2744, 3375]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Such a simple fix